# zsh: remove predicted text

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I use following settings at zsh:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
autoload predict-on
predict-on
```

When I'm typing some command like `ln` and I'm not going to use anything what is predicted (`-al` for example), how I can just decline what is already here and leave only my typed input?

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete everything from the cursor to the end of the line with the `kill-line` or `vi-kill-eol` widget.

- In *emacs* mode `kill-line` is bound to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> by default.
- In *vi* mode, `vi-kill-eol` is bound to <kbd>D</kbd> in command mode by default. So you need tor enter *vicmd* mode (default <kbd>Escape</kbd>) and then press <kbd>D</kbd>

  Alternatively, you can add a custom binding for `kill-line` in insert mode (*viins*) to have immediate access. For example, to bind it to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> run

  ```
    bindkey '^K' kill-line
  ```